# Angular2 - Materialize css autocomplete dropdown

Tags: angular, materialize

I am using materialize css autocomplete feature in angularjs but don't know how to map into json response.

//students is the interface with property id, name, email, address

```
students: Student[];

ngOnInit() {
    this._studentService.getAllActiveStudents().subscribe(data => {
    this.students = data;
});
```

How to replace json response (data:) into service response this.students

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    data: {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,
        "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
    },
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see AngularJS ... it's Angular ... Your question it's wrong..

Comment: You are right it is angular. Thanks for pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Use the instance,

```
const instance = $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        data: {
            "Apple": null,
            "Microsoft": null,
            "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
        },
        });
```

and after that

`instance.updateData(<your object>);`

Actually, I'm not sure where the `materilize` here as you is used `$` (jquery)

My using:

```
this.inst = M.Autocomplete.init(this.element.nativeElement, {
      data: {},
      minLength: 1,
      limit: 1
    });

// update

this.inst.updateData({'ME': null});
```